# Drill down in nested JSON object via the URL?

Tags: json

I'm still learning JSON. Is it possible to add parameters to the JSON url to drill down to the level I want to start? For example, the feed structure looks like this:

```
object {3}          
   feed {12}
      entry [6]
        0       {34}
        1       {34}    
        2       {34}    
        3       {34}    
        4       {34}    
        5       {34}
```

Is it possible to access the JSON url so that it starts with the `entry` array in the root?

Comment: Where is this data coming from? If the server offers you such an option then yes, otherwise no. JSON is just a format. What the contents are is up to the server which sends it to you...

Comment: It's the JSON from a published Google Sheet. The URL format is https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/YOUR-GOOGLE-ID/od6/public/values?alt=json